# Super constructor in java

Tags: java, class, constructor, super, superclass

Please explain

```
public class Contact {
    private String contactId;
   private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String phoneNumber;

public Contact(String contactId,String firstName, String lastName,   String email,        String phoneNumber) {
    super();  //what does standalone super() define? With no args here?
    this.firstName = firstName;  
    this.lastName = lastName;     //when is this used?, when more than one args to be entered?
    this.email = email;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}
```

Super() with no arguments inside mean there are more than one arguments to be defined? And is this done with the help of "this.xxx" ?

Why dint we define in the "public class Contact" itself. Why we defined again and called its arguments here?

Comment: super calls the parent class constructor in your case, Object class constructor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **Super() with no arguments inside mean there are more than one arguments to be defined?**

No, `super()` just calls the no-arg constructor of the base class, in your case `Object`.

It does nothing really. It just makes it explicit in the code, that you're constructing the base class using the no-arg constructor. In fact, if you left `super()` out, it would be added back implicitly by the compiler.

So what is the `super()` for if it's added implicitly anyway? Well, in some cases, a class does not have a no-arg constructor. Subclasses of this class *must* explicitly call some super-constructor, using for instance `super("hello")`.

> **`this.lastName = lastName; //when is this used?, when more than one args to be entered?`**

`this.lastName = lastName;` has nothing to do with `super()`. It merely states that the value of the constructor argument `lastName` should be assigned to the member variable `lastName`. This is equivalent to

```
public Contact(String contactId, String firstName, String lastNameArg,
               String email, String phoneNumber) {
    // ...
    lastName = lastNameArg;
    // ...
```

Answer (score 6):

`super()` calls the default (no-arg) constructor of the superclass. This is because in order to construct an object, you have to go through all the constructors up the hierarchy.

`super()` can be omitted - the compiler automatically inserts it there.

In your case, the superclass is `Object`