# Why does this constructor of a custom class have 'super' in its brackets?

Tags: java, android

```
public WordAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Word> words)


    {
        super(context, 0, words);
    }
```

Why would super appear in the brackets here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Super constructor in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678680/super-constructor-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Because it is calling a specific constructor in the super class. One that takes `Context, int, ArrayList<Word>` as parameters. If there was not an explicit `super` or `this` as the first line (of **any** constructor), then an *implicit* empty call to `super()` is **added**.